# Can an emulator instance send msgs to another machine?

Tags: android-emulator

Will an Android utility that sends/listens to messages via sockets be able to connect to another machine on the network from the emulator? IOW, what I want to do is send and receive messages from one XP machine to another.

Answer (score 1):

You have network access, so you should be able to setup TCP sockets.